# WordPress AJAX not displaying content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm building a site within WordPress which will display two rows of images at the start, then on button click, two more, dynamically.

I have four files involved in this process:

- **case-study-card.php**: Which holds the markup for the each card.
- **home.php**: Where the load more button is created.
- **load-more.js**
- **ajax-loaders.php**

  However, I'm stumped on where my AJAX is falling apart? I feel as if

```js
/*************/
// load-more.js
/*************/

jQuery(function($){

    $('#loadmore').click(function(){

        var column_width = $(this).data('column-width');
        var max_num_pages = $(this).data('max-num-pages');
        var ignore = $(this).data('featured');
        var post_type = $(this).data('type');

        var button = $(this),
          data = {
            action:'loadmore',
            query: loadmore_params.posts,
            page : loadmore_params.current_page,
            security : loadmore_params.security
          };  

        $.ajax({
            url : loadmore_params.ajaxurl,
            data : data,
            type : 'POST',
            beforeSend : function ( xhr ) {
                button.text('Loading...'); 
                 console.log ("before sending ajax"); // works
            },
            
            success : function( data ){
                if( data ) {
                    console.log("test")
                    button.text( 'Load More' ).prev().before(data); // insert new posts
                    loadmore_params.current_page++;

                    // where to insert new posts...
                    console.log("now inserting new posts");
                    $('.case-studies-container').find('.case-card').last().after( data );
                    console.log("found card");
                    // if it's the last page in the query, remove the button
                    if ( loadmore_params.current_page == max_num_pages )
                        button.remove(); 

                     console.log (data);

                } else {
                    // if no data, remove the button as well
                    button.remove(); 
                }
            },

            error : function(error){ 
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<!-- In case-study-card.php -->

<div class="case-card" >
  <div class="case-card__wrapper">
    <h4 class="case-card__title">
      Title
    </h4>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- in home.php
* After looping through and displaying the initial 5 cards, display the button at the bottom
-->

<?php 
  if ($the_query->found_posts > 5 ){
      echo "<div class='case-study__loadmore'><a id='loadmore'>Load more</a>";

  }
?>

<!-- ajax-loaders.php -->
<?php
function ajax_handler(){

  check_ajax_referer('load_more', 'security');
 
  //prepare arguments for query
  $args = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ), true );
  $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // we need next page to be loaded
  $args['post_status'] = 'publish';
  $args['post__not_in'] = explode(',',$_POST['exclude']);
  $args['max_num_pages'] = $_POST['max_num_pages'];
  $cols = $_POST['columns'];
  $type = $_POST['post_type'];

  query_posts( $args );
  if( have_posts() ) :
    
    // run the loop
    while( have_posts() ): the_post(); 
    endwhile;
  endif;

  
  die;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_{action}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}
 
?>
```

I believe everything after `success : function( data )` in `load-more.js` is not working and I'm not sure why? I also get a **admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)** error, a file that I have not seen or worked on in this project ...

**Edit:**

**asset-loader.php**

```
wp_localize_script( 'theme', 'loadmore_params', array(
  'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
  'posts' => json_encode( $wp_query->query_vars ), 
  'current_page' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
  'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
  'security' => wp_create_nonce("load_more")
) );


wp_localize_script( 'theme', 'repeater_loadmore_params', array(
  'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
  'current_page' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
  'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
  'security' => wp_create_nonce("repeater_field_nonce")
) );
```

**Edit 2:**

I believe the ajax handler `url : loadmore_params.ajaxurl` is working.

- When I have `url : loadmore_params.ajaxurl` the button text changes from "Load more" to "Loading".
- When I have `url : ajaxurl` the button doesn't change `beforeSend`.

Which makes me think the handler is working fine, but anything within  `success : function( data ){` isn't working and I'm not sure why.

Comment: is `loadmore_params.ajaxurl` pointing to `admin-ajax.php`?

Comment: @madalinivascu As in is it being localiized? I've edited my question to show how and where it is being localized. The only references I have to `loadmore_params` is in `load-more.js` and `asset-loader.php`

Comment: @madalinivascu - I've updated my question again... I think the ajax handler is working.

Answer (score 0):

Place your localize script also so it may be debug properly.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please note that this does not answer the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. - From Review